# Using object as key for finding values in router.get

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mongodb, mean-stack

I'm using this controller to use my service then calling my router.get, I want to use the userObject.blood_component as the searchFinder when getting the request from mongodb

**controller:**

```
var userObject = {}; 
userObject.blood_component = "find me";
Bloodstock.getStocks(userObject).then(function(data) {});
```

Then calling the api route:

**service:**

```
bloodstockFactory.getStocks = function(userObject) {
   return $http.get('/api/getStocks/', userObject);
};
```

**api.js:**

```
   router.get('/getStocks', function(req, res) {

        var newBloodneeded = req.body.blood_component; 
        console.log("the component is " + newBloodneeded ) //undefined
        Bloodstock.find({$and: [ { blood_component:newBloodneeded}]},function(err, bloodstocks) {    
        res.json({ success: true, bloodstocks: bloodstocks });

        });   
    });
```

But when it goes to api, it is undefined, what is wrong here

Comment: `GET` requests do not have a body, they have URL paramters. If you need a body, consider a `POST` or `PUT`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't send data in the GET request, you will have to pass it in URL as a query string or query parameter.

You will have to make below changes

**Controller**

```
Bloodstock.getStocks('find me').then(function(data) {});
```

**Service**

```
bloodstockFactory.getStocks = function(searchString) {
   return $http.get('/api/getStocks/?search=' + searchString, userObject);
};
```

Now in API, you can get search string using `req.query.search`